# when to use the "new" keyword with structs in c#

Tags: c#, .net, struct, gdi+

I am working with GDI+ and need to create a Brush or Pen. In most cases I should use a "color Struct". Searching around I see two different styles: One is like this:

```
 Brush B1 = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));
```

and the other is:

```
Color myColor;
myColor = Color.FromArgb(255,0,0);
Brush B2 = new SolidBrush(myColor);
```

Can anyone describe how can we use a Color without declaring an instance of the Struct with new operator that calls the default constructor.

Comment: The `new Color()` happens inside `Color.FromArgb()`, is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes i don't understand how to using Color without calling a constructor

Comment: FromArgb is a static method, no instance method

Comment: Yes, That is, I didn't know this before, thank you

Comment: but even if the FromArgb() is static how can i do that
var myColor = Color.FromArgb(255,0,0);
this line conflict me, but i think this method return Color type

Comment: @Ahmed.Marzouk please can you be very explicit about what exactly is "conflict" you? If you clarify what your actual question / concern is, we can help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is going on here is that the interesting constructor is non-public, and you must create the value via a `static` utility method. You can achieve the same thing trivially in your own code:

```
struct Indirect
{
    private readonly int value;
    private Indirect(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static Indirect Create(int value)
    {
        return new Indirect(value);
    }
}

struct Direct
{
    private readonly int value;
    public Direct(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = Indirect.Create(42);
        var y = new Direct(42);
    }
}
```

Sometimes the expected usage is that the caller uses `new`; sometimes the expected usage is that the caller gets handed values from a helper method. In the case of `Color`: the latter. In the case of `SolidBrush`: the former. Note that this can be the case for both `struct` and `class` types - that is not the distinguishing factor.

In the case of `Color`, there are actually many more fields than you see directly; for example, `knownColor`, `name`, `state` - *separately* to the ARGB values. Some colors are "known" (from pre-defined named lists); some colors are ad-hoc (from ARGB data). The way you get the color determines these additional values.

Answer (score 2):

The constructors of the type `System.Drawing.Color` are `private` and `internal`, meaning you can't call them from your code.

You'll need to instantiate a color through the [given static methods and properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) it contains, like `Color.FromArgb()` or `Color.White`.

As for the comments, which now make the question clear: those methods and properties are [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx), which means you don't call them on an instance (`new Color().White`) but on the *type* (`Color.White`).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from its behavior, the method

```
Color.FromArgb(int red, int green, int blue)
```

most probably calls

```
new Color()
```

in its implementation, i.e. it declares an instance of the struct Color with the new operator.

Answer (score 0):

Both implementations are equal, however

```
  Brush B1 = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));
```

is shorter. I'd rather use even *shorter* in the case

```
  Brush B1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red); // R = 255, G = 0, B = 0 is just "Red"
```

Note, that `Brush` is `IDisposable`, that's why it seems that you have put it

```
  using (Brush B1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)) {
    ... // Working with brush 
  }
```